# Colocar um variável dentro de um spin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
import spintax

nome1 = input("Nome: ")
nome2 = input("Nome: ")
nome3 = input("Nome: ")
for z in range(0,10):
    c = (spintax.spin("{noite|dia|tarde}")
    print("Boa {}".format(c))
```

Queria colocar as variáveis `nome` dentro de uma nova variável parecida com a variável `c`. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, devemos criar a stirng com o padrão a ser usado dinamicamente. Existem várias formas para se fazer isso:

- #### Utilizar concatenação

  Você pode concatenar strings no Python utilizando o operador `+`. Assim:

  ```
  nome1 = "Foo"
  nome2 = "Bar"
  nome3 = "Baz"

  print("{" + nome1 + "|" + nome2 + "|" + nome3 + "}") # {Foo|Bar|Baz}
  ```
- #### O método [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format)

  Você já está o utilizando em seu código para imprimir o texto gerado. Pode utilizá-lo também para gerar o padrão dinamicamente. Assim:

  ```
  nome1 = "Foo"
  nome2 = "Bar"
  nome3 = "Baz"

  print("{{{}|{}|{}}}".format(nome1, nome2, nome3)) # {Foo|Bar|Baz}
  ```

  Note que, como `str.format` utiliza as chaves (`{` e `}`) para delimitar o local em que a formatação será realizada, você deve utilizar `{{` e `}}` para inserir `{` ou `}`, respectivamente, na string. [Saiba mais na documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).
- #### Utilizar strings literais formatadas ([f-strings](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals))

  O funcionamento das f-strings é, basicamente, uma interpolação de variáveis em uma string (embora possa ficar bem mais complexo que isso — mas não entrarei nesse mérito). O padrão de funcionamento é, também, similar ao método `str.format` (que vimos anteriormente), mas ocorre em um literal de string. Veja:

  ```
  nome1 = "Foo"
  nome2 = "Bar"
  nome3 = "Baz"

  print(f"{{{nome1}|{nome2}|{nome3}}}")  # {Foo|Bar|Baz}
  ```

  <sup>Note que, assim como com o método `str.format`, há de se utilizar `{{` ou `}}` para inserir as chaves na própria string.</sup>

---

Agora você escolhe um jeito para criar o padrão. Utilizando as f-strings, teremos algo como:

```
import spintax

nome1 = input("Nome: ")
nome2 = input("Nome: ")
nome3 = input("Nome: ")

for z in range(0, 10):
    c = spintax.spin("{noite|dia|tarde}")
    n = spintax.spin(f"{{{nome1}|{nome2}|{nome3}}}")

    print(f"Boa {c}, {n}!")
```

Observe que removi um parêntese extra que estava errado no código (causando um erro de sintaxe). Note também que, para padronizar, troquei o `str.format` no `print` por uma f-string. Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@lffg/SOpt-482764#main.py).

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso responde sua pergunta

```
import spintax

nome1 = input("Nome: ")
nome2 = input("Nome: ")
nome3 = input("Nome: ")

for z in range(0,10):
    c = spintax.spin("{noite|dia|tarde}")
    n = spintax.spin("{" + f"{nome1}|{nome2}|{nome3}" + "}")
    print(f"Olá {n}, bom(a) {c}")
```

Breves comentários

1. No código do seu post estava `c = (spintax...` e este parêntesis não estava sendo fechado, porém como ele não é necessário, retirei.
2. Para incluir os dados concatenei strings e utilizei `f-string` (disponível a partir da versão 3.6 do Python

Espero que ajude.